# how to run code after 2 observables emit values and get results of emitted values?

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 observables
and my code is like this  [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzkzdi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
const obs1$ = of(1); // mock http call
const obs2$ = of(2);

obs1$.subscribe( (value1) => {
this.first = value1; // populating values from subscribe
})

obs2$.subscribe( (value2) => {
this.second = value2; // populating values from subscribe
})
forkJoin([obs1$,obs2$]).subscribe(() => {
if(this.first === 0 || this.second === 0) // checking if the values are not empty
console.log('empty')
});
```

How can I consolidate these 3 methods using RxJs, right now there are double http calls once from subscribe another from forkjoin.
I want to populate when both observables(together) have finished and get results also to populate `first` and `second` and check their values too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly call forkJoin and access to the resultat :

```
forkJoin([obs1$, obs2$]).subscribe((result) => {
    this.first = results[0];
    this.second = results[1]
    if (this.first === 0 || this.second === 0) // checking if the values are not empty
        console.log('empty')
});
```

Comment: `const obs1$: Observable<someInterface> = ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in forkJoin itself i.e -

```
const obs1$ = of(1).pipe(take(1)); // mock http call
const obs2$ = of(2).pipe(take(1));


forkJoin([obs1$,obs2$]).subscribe(([obs1Result, obs2Result]) => {
    this.first = obs1Result;
    this.second = obs2Result;
});
```

Also you may want to use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` because it waits for both the observable to complete, while `combineLatest` emits a value, each time source observable emits a value after all observables have emitted at least one value.

Comment: I don't understand your comment correctly but if you want to typecast, you may try 
```this.first = (obs1Result as any)```